# Show all posts in one page with feature image

Tags: php, wordpress

I want show all posts in one page with their feature image like following image and after click on image i want to go details page. How can i do this?[image]

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code ?

Comment: $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id','post_type'=>'post' ) ); But it returns nothing when i placed this code in a page.